# Error: Value of SET_STRING_ELT() must be a 'CHARSXP' not a 'character' in dplyr group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a super random error when using `group_by` in `dplyr` as follows

```
dat %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(score = score[1])
```

where `dat` is a `data.frame` with factor/character column `variable` and `score` is a double. The error I get is this:

```
Value of SET_STRING_ELT() must be a 'CHARSXP' not a 'character'
```

- It happens regardless of the name of `variable`.
- Regardless of the computation (e.g. `score[1]`).
- I can group by any other variable.
- Both variables seem fine. I can marginally do all sorts of computations with `variable` or `score`. Variable has only repeated entries "arima" and "prophet", no `NA`s.
- Also, the error message shows up only sometimes. Most often the R session simply terminates due to a fatal error.

It's driving me crazy...

I googled the error and couldn't find good help, except for narrowing it down, which is what I did, i.e. a simple `group_by` computation. Further, I restarted the R session, restarted the computer, updated my R version and the `dplyr` package, which is now on version 1.07.
I use R version 4.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Any thoughts on what could possibly produce this error?

**Edit**
I cannot provide a reproducible sample with simulated data as it only happens with the particular data. Here I uploaded the data that is causing the error https://filebin.net/9pywc544hsmgm2p3

Then run the following code

```
A <- readRDS("dat.rds") %>% 
    group_by(variable) %>% 
    mutate(score = score[1])
```

Interestingly, if you group by `A[1:nrow(A), ]` instead of `A` it works, although it is the same data.

**Edit 2:**
I could now run the computation a couple of times, but at some point I always get a fatal error for the same computation. I get the feeling that this seems specific to my system. So probably I have to reinstall everything.

**Edit 3:**
Doing `as.numeric(score)` solves the issue. So it seems something was up with the name attributes of score. However, they do not look suspicious and all have the same name, which is "new_confirmed10".

Comment: Can you edit your question with a small example dataset which reproduces the error please.

Comment: I had similar issues after updating RStudio to version 2021.09.0+351. Have you done so recently?

Comment: @user20650: Cannot reproduce the error on an example dataset, so I uploaded the small dataset (see Edit).

Comment: @DonaldSeinen No, not very recently, must be a couple of months ago since I last updated R studio

Comment: Thanks 'Nic, however after downloading I was unable to open the file.

Comment: Indeed, that is weird. Anyhow, I found a workaround, so I won't bother uploading the data again, unless you particularly interested in the causes of the error. Thanks nonetheless for trying to help, much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, please do upload it again.  Maybe try putting it somewhere else?

Comment: Just did, I tried and could read it now.

Comment: I downloaded it, and can reproduce the bug.  I'll see if I can track down the cause.

Comment: I am getting the same error when calling `library(tidyverse)`, which is very weird because I was using RStudio normally until now. I just closed the project and opened another project in RStudio, which is when this error started appearing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

That's an internal error in C code that implements an R function.  It should never occur in user code.  This is definitely a bug somewhere.  You can probably narrow down the location slightly by running `traceback()` immediately after seeing it.  That will list all the R functions that are active at the time the error happened, and might give the location of the R function that called the buggy C code.

Please put together a reproducible example (i.e. give us a way to construct `dat` so that we can reproduce it on our systems).  Someone here on SO will be able to locate the cause of the error, and maybe be able to tell you a workaround, or tell the author of the code how to fix it.

If you can't do that, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you, but here's some general advice:

- Don't use packages or package versions that are only on Github, stick to CRAN packages which have generally received better testing.
- If you are developing your own C/C++ code and it is somehow involved here, you need to use `gdb` or `lldb` to do C-level debugging.  If you haven't used those before, it's not easy.

EDITED to add:

After examining the uploaded version of the `dat.rds` file, I think I've discovered part of the problem.  Running this code:

```
dat <- readRDS("dat.rds")
table(names(dat$score))
```

I can see that the names of `dat$score` are 744 copies of `"new_confirmed10"`.  Having repeated names is unusual, but legal.  However, the length of `dat$score` is 1488 (the same as the number of rows of `dat`), and as far as I know it's never legal to have a different number of names than the length of the object.  (If you only assign names to some elements, you should get name `NA` on the others.)

When you run your code, something in the mutate call crashes, because it assumes the object is well-formed, and it's not.  So this isn't a bug in `dplyr`, but I think it's a bug in whatever code created the object in `dat.rds`.  Do you have any record of how it was created?

Comment: It is difficult to get the traceback, since now I often get fatal errors and the session terminates... Interestingly, I just ran the code, it worked for once. Then I repeated it, and the session terminated again. It is really strange, never had anything like this

Comment: In that case you'd be helped a lot by using gdb or lldb, but if you're not comfortable with that, there's not much choice but an old fashioned binary search:  take out half your code, and run it.  Still have the bug?  Take out half of what is left.  Fixed the bug?  Try again to confirm, then put back what you took out, and take out a different part of the code.  Eventually you'll get to a minimal example and will have narrowed things down a lot.

Comment: Never used `gdb` or `lldb` before, so not sure if I'd be able to debug it easily. I did the old fashioned way and narrowed it down to the very simple `dat %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(score = score[1])`. I don't know where to locate the error further and it is also strange that I don't always get the error. In one out of every fourth execution of the exact same code with the exact same data it works somehow. How can this possibly be?

Comment: @Nic:  I've edited my answer to give more info about the problem, and to ask how the `dat.rds` file was created.

Comment: There is lots of preprocessing involved and the names are added at some point when doing `dat %>% dplyr::select(x) %>% unlist()`. After that the names are kept throughout the rest of the preprocessing until `x` is used to compute `score`. I actually don't need the names, which is why `as.numeric()` was a simple fix fore me. But it is interesting to see the names are only half the length of its numeric variable. I'll should better check if I duplicated something somewhere. Thanks for investigating!

Comment: I'd try to identify the point at which `length(names(dat$score))` becomes different from `length(dat$score)`.  I'm pretty sure that step uses some bad C/C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of solved it. `score` was a `Named num`. After doing `as.numeric(score)` it worked. Still don't why the name attributes caused this error though (they seem all normal), but so be it. I realized this once I exported data as `.csv` and `.rds` and the error occured only when I reloaded the `.rds` data, so I figured it must be related with some data attributes.

Comment: The file you uploaded gives errors on reading, so together with the info above, I'd guess the names are corrupted somehow, and that's causing the problem.  Can you print `names(dat$score)`?

Comment: I edited the question, the names are all the same: "new_confirmed10". I also uploaded the file again.

Comment: Thank you for re-uploading; I can read it well with `d <- readRDS(".../dat.rds")`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for re-uploading; I can read it well with `d <- readRDS(".../dat.rds")`   and then easily see what @user2554330 said:

```
> d <- readRDS("<....>/dat.rds")
> str(d)
'data.frame':   1488 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ facet_var: chr  "AUT" "AUT" "AUT" "AUT" ...
 $ date     : Date, format: "2020-04-26" "2020-04-27" ...
 $ variable : Factor w/ 2 levels "arima","prophet": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ score    : Named num  2.74e-06 2.41e-06 2.48e-06 2.39e-06 2.79e-06 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:744] "new_confirmed10" "new_confirmed10" "new_confirmed10" "new_confirmed10" ...
>
```

so the question does remain: *How* was the invalid `score` column created?  I  postulate it was by some C code which is working invalidly, as I don't think you could use simple R code to create this.

One "proof" that this is an invalid object, working  reproducibly is

```
> ds <- d$score
> dput(ds)

 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dput(ds)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

Comment: Is this about "inner names" of a data frame? "Inner names" are something a `tibble` supports but a data frame seemingly not (see https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/837).

Comment: See my comment to @user2554330. The `score` column is the end product of computations done with a nested `tibble` in dplyer, which are finally unnested.

Comment: @Helix123:  That seems like a plausible source of the issue:  a tibble had the names, it was converted to a dataframe, then the dataframe was modified.  The dataframe code would assume there were no names, so might not have updated them properly.  This has been fixed in tibble 3.1.5, the current release.

Answer (score 0):

### I got that error from `read.csv` thustly:

Rscript --version: 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  Value of SET_STRING_ELT() must be a 'CHARSXP' not a '...'
Calls: bag_model_smart_pdn_shift_rotation_strat ... load_unpack_random_base_model_with_min_pdn_shift_diversity -> read.csv -> read.table -> scan
Environment:

  1: bag_model_smart_pdn_shift_rotation_strat(train_labels_0_1, test_labels_0_1, prod_labels_0_1, best_train_acc_imp, be
  2: #97: load_unpack_random_base_model_with_min_pdn_shift_diversity(superior_models, bagmodel_sm, pdn_shift_forced_uniq
  3: #67: read.csv(tr_filename, header = training_csv_includes_header_row)
  4: read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.c
  5: scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, nmax = nrows, skip = 0, na.strings = na.strings
```

The error is produced by method `scan` under `read.table`.  What had happened is the text file that read.csv was consuming was copied from a program that suffered a network error and half-copied file, and left the target file with some sort of half-written character.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Encodings-for-CHARSXPs

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format